# Find the equivalent of CurrentViewMode in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I'm browsing a local folder within a webBrowser control and I'm using .NET 4.7:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("C:/some_folder");
```

This folder displays pdfs in vertical line with the last update, the size and the type.
I just need to find the property that will allow me to display this list in "mosaic view" with the icons bigger and without any extra info like the last update, the size or the type of document ...
After somme digging I found out some vb.net users got the property webBrowser.Document.CurrentViewMode. I have indeed webBrowser.Document but nothing such as CurrentViewMode... It should be a silly thing I guess as this is the equivalent of right-clicking and choose properties of the displayed list of documents...)

Thanks for any help

Comment: is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Comment: hey @JackJJun-MSFT, thanks for answering, I replied to your comment. I'd like to know, if you don't mind, more about the class you used and how I can applied to the case below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, I can not find a direct property called CurrentViewMode in webbrower.document.

However, I find another way to change the view of webbrowser.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private const int LV_VIEW_ICON = 0x0;

        private const int LV_VIEW_DETAILS = 0x1;

        private const int LV_VIEW_SMALLICON = 0x2;

        private const int LV_VIEW_LIST = 0x3;

        private const int LV_VIEW_TILE = 0x4;

        private const int EM_HIDEBALLOONTIP = 0x1504;

        private const int LVM_SETVIEW = 0x108E;

        private const string ListViewClassName ="SysListView32";
        private static readonly HandleRef NullHandleRef = new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(HandleRef hwndParent, EnumChildrenCallback lpEnumFunc, HandleRef  lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint RealGetWindowClass(IntPtr hwnd, [Out] StringBuilder pszType,uint cchType);

        private delegate bool EnumChildrenCallback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

        private HandleRef listViewHandle;

        private void FindListViewHandle()
        {
            this.listViewHandle = NullHandleRef;

            EnumChildrenCallback lpEnumFunc = new EnumChildrenCallback(EnumChildren);

            EnumChildWindows(new HandleRef(this.webBrowser1, this.webBrowser1.Handle), lpEnumFunc, NullHandleRef);
        }
        private bool EnumChildren(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);

            RealGetWindowClass(hwnd, sb, 100);

            if (sb.ToString() == ListViewClassName)
                this.listViewHandle = new HandleRef(null, hwnd);

            return true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("D:/pdf");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(LV_VIEW_ICON);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(LV_VIEW_DETAILS);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(LV_VIEW_SMALLICON);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(LV_VIEW_LIST);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(LV_VIEW_TILE);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FindListViewHandle();

            int view = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

            SendMessage((IntPtr)this.listViewHandle, LVM_SETVIEW, (IntPtr)view, (IntPtr)0);
        }
    }
```

Update the explanation for the code:

First, We used `FindListViewHandle()` to find the listview control's handle(`listViewHandle`) in the webbrowser, so I used `EnumChildWindows` method to iterate child control.

Second, we can use the combobox1 to store different listview style.

Third, the message `LVM_SETVIEW` indicates that sets the view of a list-view control.

Finally, `SendMessage` method will find the listviewcontrol in the webbrowser and it will set the view of list-view control and set its style by the combobox value.

Here are some reference come from Microsoft doc you can refer to.

[LVM_SETVIEW message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setview)

[EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows)

[SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage)

Result:

[image]

Comment: First of, Thank you Jack. I was just trying to adapt your code to my use. In my case basically, I click on a picture box that triggers the view of the local files. It's at this moment (still within the doubleclik event of the picture box) I need to display one of the views you proposed.  So I try to understand what does what in your code. If you don't mind, a bit of explanation would speed up my searching process :)

Comment: @James06, sorry for the late reply, I have updated some explanation in the answer now. Besides, you can change button_click to picturebox_Double_click event if you want to use picturebox to display the views.

Comment: Hi Jack, again sorry for my late reply. Indeed I used your solution and thank you very much for the sharing